# cant show text of combobox in textbox wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, combobox

hi guy i use this code

```
private void combobox1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    text_f1.text = combobox1.Text;
}
```

my first record is  "car"
and Second record is "phone"
...

in first when i select "car" don't show anything when i select second or other record show me "car"

It's always a bit behind

after this problem i try use this code

```
text_f1.text = combobox1.DisplayMemberPath;
```

show me

```
"MahName"
```

its wrong

what should i do ?

Comment: `combobox1.Text` is the editable text of the combo-box (which lags a bit behind). What you need is the selected item `text_f1 = (string)combobox1.SelectedItem;` (assuming that the combo-box contains strings).

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do it in **XAML** using *ElementBinding*.

```
<ComboBox x:Name="comboBox"/>
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=SelectedItem.MahName, ElementName=comboBox}"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

`combobox1.Text` is the editable text of the combo-box (which lags a bit behind when the selection changes). The exact solution depends on what kind of items the combo-box contains and how it was configured.

If it contains strings, you can write

```
text_f1.Text = (string)combobox1.SelectedItem;
```

If it contains objects of a class `Article` (as an example), you can get the text with

```
if (combobox1.SelectedItem is Article article) {
    text_f1.Text = article.MahName;
}
```

Or if the `ToString` method of the items has been overridden

```
if (combobox1.SelectedItem != null) {
    text_f1.Text = combobox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
}
```

or

```
text_f1.Text = combobox1.SelectedItem?.ToString();
```

This last version assigns `null` to `text_f1` if there is no selected item. See: [?. and ?[] null-conditional operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators)

Comment: i use it in                                                
     if(Convert.ToString((datagrid_customer.SelectedCells[1].Column.GetCellContent(datagrid_customer.SelectedItem) as TextBlock).Text) == combobox1.Text)        and when use your code , app is crashing